# Linq to SQL - Format DateTime in Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm have .dbml Linq to SQL class named DExamination.dbml

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Examination")]
public partial class Examination : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _Id;

    private string _Title;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _StartDate;
}
...
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_StartDate", DbType="DateTime")]
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this._StartDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._StartDate != value))
            {
                this.OnStartDateChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._StartDate = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("StartDate");
                this.OnStartDateChanged();
            }
        }
    }
...
```

Display in Edit

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Examination.StartDate)%>
```

How to format StartDate like "dd/MM/yyyy"

I've tried add DisplayFormat above ...

```
[global::System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_StartDate", DbType="DateTime")]
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this._StartDate;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._StartDate != value))
            {
                this.OnStartDateChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._StartDate = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("StartDate");
                this.OnStartDateChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

but not working

Anyone have solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a directory `EditorTemplates` in your `Shared` view directory.
Then add a control named `DateTime.ascx` with the following code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DateTime>" %>
<%:Html.TextBox(string.Empty,Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) %>
```

Then you can call it with

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Examination.StartDate) %>
```

Comment: This would be applied to **every** DateTime model property where you chose to use `EditorFor` which I take it from the poster's comment is what he was looking for.  If you want to conditionally apply a custom editor/display template to one or more model properties, however, you could use the 'EditorFor/DisplayFor` override that takes a templateName as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decorate your model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }
```

And the attribute is already there in your code, just the wrong order.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Examination.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))%>
```

Comment: It will not work, the html helper extension takes only property as argument